# How to transpose file in unix?

Tags: unix, transpose

I have one file

```
ColA   ColB   ColC
2.34   2.83   8.45
4.34   2.26   7.46
3.34   2.25   4.45
```

How can i transpose this file?

Regards

Comment: What have you tried? The community will gladly assist you, however we will not write your code for you.

Comment: I have written C++ program to implement it. But now i don't want to use C++. Just want to do it in unix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with `awk`:

```
awk '{print $1, $3, $2}' file
```